# "M13ProgressView" - not working in landscape

Tags: objective-c, github

I don't know about any restriction for asking question in Stack Overflow about the third party code. However, i like to ask and if any problem about that question means then i'll close my question.

If you know about the "M13ProgressView"  open source tool means, then you may be helpful for my question.

Question: "M13ProgressView" not worked for landscape. When rotating the device to landscape, the superview changing to the landscape but the "M13ProgressView" displaying vertically(both simulator & device) not excepted as horizontally. How could i fix this?

Comment: Most of the googling results gives only about MBProgressHUD not about M13Progressview. So i cannot get any idea.

Answer (score 0):

That's an iOS8 fix by Apple, that breaks workarounds.
Prior to iOS8 code needs to take care of rotation if it is being added to the window.
Now on iOS8+ handles automatically, the windows subviews are rotated due to orientation changes.

So you need to find code where rotation transform is applied, and disable it if OS version is greater than 8.0.
For example here is the [commit that fixed iOS8 rotation issue on MBProgrgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/commit/06fdc08431a46407d8be4492245bc8ea07ca65a8)